# Why isn't circe available in my sbt common project, tests area?

Tags: scala, circe

I have a multi project sbt project.

My common project has circe as a dependancy:

```
  object circeDeps {
    val core    = "io.circe" %% "circe-core"    % circeVersion
    val generic = "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % circeVersion
    val parser  = "io.circe" %% "circe-parser"  % circeVersion
  }
```

Added to my common dependency collection:

```
val commonDeps: Seq[ModuleID] = Seq(
    ..
    circeDeps.core,
    circeDeps.generic,
    circeDeps.parser
  ) ++ specs2Deps.map(_ % Test) ++ silencer.bundle
```

When I run a unit test, I am getting an error:

```
object circe is not a member of package io
[error] import io.circe.parser
```

What am I doing wrong here?

(yes I reloaded sbt many times now - the imports work fine in the common/src/main/scala project but not in my common/src/test/...)

Comment: Maybe you have some `io` import before trying to import **circe**?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez no I don't have anything...this is strange!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I had ```import scala.io``` you were correct!  I moved my imports above.  What's going on I don't understand why it would be an issue...

Comment: Well there is no `circe` package inside `scala.io` there is a `circe` package inside `_root_.io`. So, changing the order of the imports fixes the problem. Another solution would be not importing `scala.io` but rather what you need, and the final one would be `import _root_.io.circe`